# How to do multiple choice selection with bash using if elif and else

Tags: bash

Team,

I am not able to figure out what is the issue with my indentation or syntax. can any one hint? I tried it on linux and i get below error:

error: output

```
line 23: syntax error near unexpected token `['
line 23: `    if [ $CLUSTER_NAME == prod.$test_environment ]; then'

#!/bin/bash
sops_ops() {
  sops --version
  if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    echo "proceed sops ops"
  else
    echo "check sops binary"
  fi

  read -p 'Enter cluster_NAME: ' CLUSTER_NAME
  test_environment="test.nvaa.com"
  test1_environment="test1.nvaa.com"

  case "${$CLUSTER_NAME}" in
  prod.$test_environment) ;;
  dev.$test1_environment) ;;
  *) echo "Invalid option: ${CLUSTER_NAME}" 1>&2 && exit 1 ;;

    if [ $CLUSTER_NAME == prod.$test_environment ]; then
            printf "got test cluster $CLUSTER_NAME"
    elif [ $CLUSTER_NAME == dev.$test1_environment ];then
            printf "got test1 cluster $NAME"
            echo "not found cluster"
    else
            echo "Environment not available"
    fi
}
sops_ops
```

Comment: *"I tried it on linux and i get below error"* What error?

Comment: added output above script

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Where's the `esac`?

Comment: OMG.. esac was missing. Thanks a lot. add it as answer. i will mark

Answer (score 0):

You're are missing `esac`. Add it after the following snippet :

```
case "${$CLUSTER_NAME}" in
  prod.$test_environment) ;;
  dev.$test1_environment) ;;
  *) echo "Invalid option: ${CLUSTER_NAME}" 1>&2 && exit 1 ;;
```

Comment: It was answered by choroba

Comment: He didn't post it as an answer so I did to help someone with it in the future. If you have a problem though, no worries. Ask him to answer it and I'll delete my answer. Happy?

Comment: its about getting credit to one to who answered first. No feelings at all and hope you understand that.